# jQuery how to change value of textbox in a column at a specific index?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how I can change the value of a textbox in a column at a specific index. I know I can do something similar to this code using:

```
$('#gv [id*=txtPrice]').slice(row_index).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

However, I get an error when I do the following:

```
$('#gv [id*=txtPrice]').slice(row_index).text("0");
```

Is there a way to change values of a textbox in a column starting at a specific index?

Comment: textbox ? Do you meen a table ? Can you put some html please ?

Comment: Did you try `$('#gv [id*=txtPrice]').slice(row_index).val("0");`

Comment: @adeneo...I just had a facepalm moment. I keep messing up between .text and .val in regards to textboxes and labels. Thanks. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by textbox you mean an `<input type="text" />`, you want to use `.val()` to set the value, not `.text()`, as pointed ouy by @adeneo in the comments.

```
$('#gv [id*=txtPrice]').slice(row_index).val("0");
```

Comment: Yes, I just realized that. It's been a long day. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/PEB5J/

html:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
<td>row 1, cell 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
<td>row 2, cell 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
    $('table td').eq(1).text('custom');
});
```

if you want every td at that index from every tr I will use .each(): http://fiddle.jshell.net/PEB5J/1/

js:

```
$(function(){
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        $(this).children().eq(1).text('custom');
    });
});
```